# HBase scanner exception: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers

Tags: scala, hbase

Meet an exception while trying to get the next row in the scanner(HBase ResultScanner), below is the part of the code, the exception occurs at "**val results = scanner.next(numRows)**"

```
val scan = new Scan(rowStart, rowEnd)
val cFamily: String = "c"
scan.addFamily(cFamily.getBytes)
scan.setCaching(numRows)
val table = hbaseConn.getTable(hbaseTableName.getTableName(baseTableName))
val scanner = table.getScanner(scan)
var done: Boolean = false
var rowProcessed: Long = 0
val results = scanner.next(numRows)
```

The Exception is as below

```
[hconnection-0x16f9965f-metaLookup-shared--pool4-t1] o.a.h.h.c.RpcRetryingCallerImpl [RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:132] Call exception, tries=6, retries=36, started=4611 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=Call to hbase_cluster_hostname/ip_address:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane., details=row 'My_table_name,�(�5:�^]^?,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hbase_cluster_hostname,16020,1626108747058, seqNum=-1, see https://s.apache.org/timeout, exception=java.io.IOException: Call to hbase_cluster_hostname/ip_address:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load SIMPLE, KERBEROS, and DIGEST authentication providers. Classpath is not sane.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$200(AbstractRpcClient.java:91
```

I meet this issue after I updated my HBase client version to 2.2.3, Not sure what does this exception means and how to fix it. Has anyone met a similar issue before? Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: @Filip I am using JDK 8

Comment: Maybe you can try the advice [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-25338).